# Vaadin 14 spinner in grid

Tags: asynchronous, grid, vaadin14

i'm loading data list to my grid in thread asynchronously so when page is loaded then i have empty grid and rows apear afte a while. I would like to let the user know that data in grid are loading by adding some sort of spinner in middle of it. I know that i can add dialog that cannot be closed by user and close it in code after data is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in feature in the framework yet for this. But one approach to do this yourself is to stack Grid and Div (or other component) with the message or the Spinner on top of each other as empty Grid wont have content obscuring the Div behind it. There is live demo and code in [Vaadin's Cookbook](https://cookbook.vaadin.com/grid-message-when-empty) about it. The code needed is too long to copy here.

There is feature request ticket in the component repository of Vaadin: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/2043

Comment: It is very interested for me too. It looks like we need something like Tooltip component upgrade. With additional functionality like server-side control of visibility spinner component. Maybe you can point me at how to connect spinner component to the Grid for example? I tried to do it myself for two days, but there is buggy in result. I tried to wrap Grid component to Div with Spinner component additionally.